# Django password hasher with username in hash

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, password-hash

Maybe a dumb question, but if possible, what's the best way of writing a BasePasswordHasher subclass using username as a part of the salt? I'm rewriting a site from scratch and used this approach in php. The problem is accessing the username in a password hasher. I would be really happy to resolve this as a LOT of users would lose their passwords otherwise, so a big thanks in advance!

PHP Code:

```
function passHash($login, $pass)
{
    return md5(md5($pass).'salt'.$login);
}
```

Comment: Do you have this original algorithm? Also any code that you have written so far?

Comment: Edited the original question to include the original code. Didn't start implementing it yet as that's not the problem. I started reading https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/passwords/ and saw the inputs doesn't contain the user object, or anything i could make use of. I'm pretty new @ Django.

Comment: Python has an MD5 module `import md5`, and in order to get a user object in a django view you have to snag it with something like `user_object = request.user` (A LOT of interesting stuff is passed in with request) after you have the user object, you can get a lot of info from it like `user_object.username` or `user_object.is_authenticated()`

Comment: So request.user is also available in this stage of the login process?

Comment: Hmm. I can say with certainty that this is possible -- I once ran a Django site which had merged via acquisition with a Rails shop and acquired the userbases of a few other startups both with their own hashing mechanisms -- but it's been long enough that I don't remember any of the details.

Comment: Edited the question to clarify the problem is accessing the username in a password hasher. Or did the site you mentioned also use usernames in password hashes?

Comment: `request.user` is ALWAYS available in views, as long as they get passed in `request`, i think if the user is not authenticated, `request.user.username` returns `None`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you noticed, this cannot be done in the password hasher alone. The password hasher does not have information about the user, only the password and hash. I think you have two options.

First, and probably best, is to write a custom [authentication backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/). At the authentication backend level, we have access to the username and raw password. It would look like this

```
# settings.py
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS=(
    'myapp.backends.LegacyBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

# myapp.backends
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.utils.encoding import force_bytes
import hashlib

class LegacyBackend(ModelBackend):

    # We only need to override the authenticate method
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        # most of this is copied directly from ModelBackend's authenticate method
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        if username is None:
            username = kwargs.get(UserModel.USERNAME_FIELD)
        try:
            user = UserModel._default_manager.get_by_natural_key(username)

            # This is the normal route that hands off to the password hasher pipeline
            # but we will sidestep it entirely and verify the password here
            #
            # if user.check_password(password):
            #    return user

            pwhash = hashlib.md5(force_bytes(password)).hexdigest()
            hash = hashlib.md5(force_bytes(pwhash+"salt"+username)).hexdigest()
            if hash == user.password:
                # update the user's password if you want, so you can phase out this backend
                user.set_password(password)
                user.save(update_fields=["password"])
                return user

        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            UserModel().set_password(password)
```

Note that I haven't tested this code, but it should work as advertised. In addition, you don't have conflicts with new users, and old users will have their passwords updated to the new hashing algorithm (default is PBKDF2+SHA256? not sure).

The second option is to write a one-off script to modify your database so the `user.password` fields look like `legacymd5$username+salt$hash`. Then you can write your custom password hasher as planned.

Comment: Don't yet know why, but you have to call user.save(update_fields=['password']) after updating the password in the try block for the login to work. Maybe you could edit the answer.

Comment: @Kukosk you are correct, an oversight on my part. `user.set_password` does not force a save. I'll edit the answer

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who finds this post as I did, everything still works as expected, except one thing.  On Django 2.1, I found I had to add "request" as the first argument in the authenticate method.  They must have added passing this thru at some point.  I was silently failing the auth and had no idea why.